# Bash Script for listing subdirectories and files in textfile

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I need a Script that writes the directory and subdirectory in a text-file.

For example the script lies in /Mainfolder and in this folder are four other folders. Each contains several files.

Now I would like the script to write the path of each file in the textfile.

```
Subfolder1/File1.dat
Subfolder1/File2.dat
Subfolder2/File1.dat
Subfolder3/File1.dat
Subfolder4/File1.dat
Subfolder4/File2.dat
```

Important is that there is no slash in front of the listing.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `find` command:

```
find Mainfolder > outputfile
```

and if you only want the files listed, do

```
find Mainfolder -type f > outputfile
```

You can also strip the leading `./` if you search the current directory, with the `%P` format option:

```
find . -type f -printf '%P\n' > outputfile
```

Comment: the last `find` line should be the answer to the Q! +1 for the usage of find build-in printf support.

Answer (score 1):

If your bash version is high enough, you can do it like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
echo ** > yourtextfile
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution assumes that the subdirectories contain only files -- they do not contain any directory in turn.

```
find . -type f -print | sed 's|^.*/S|S|'
```

I have created a single file in each of the four subdirectories. The original output is:

```
./Subfolder1/File1.dat
./Subfolder4/File4.dat
./Subfolder2/File2.dat
./Subfolder3/File3.dat
```

The filtered output is:

```
Subfolder1/File1.dat
Subfolder4/File4.dat
Subfolder2/File2.dat
Subfolder3/File3.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this find with `-exec`:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'f="{}"; echo "${f:2}"' \;
```

This will print all files starting from current paths by removing `./` from front.